# Bridging between mqtt brokers in meteor

Tags: meteor, mqtt, mosquitto

My question is about mosquitto.conf file while bridging,Well..I am running 2 same meteor apps on different ports on my pc.In which One meteor app contains mosquitto broker running on localhost and the app contains mosquitto broker running on cloud(address:ec2-13-211-229-85.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1883).Now I have to provide bridge between these mosquitto brokers(between 2 apps) and my topic in this case is 1234567890.I referred so many documents but still I am in confuse.
I have created bridge.conf file in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d directory in ubuntu,bridge.conf file information is as follows:

```
connection mqtt
address ec2-13-211-229-85.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1883
topic 1234567890 both
try_private true
clientid test
cleansession true
notification true
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_attempt_unsubscribe true
start_type automatic
```

In the above file if I am not wrong, I gave random name to connection field and clientid field(i.e mqtt and test respectively).
Next,I restarted the mosquitto.Then I checked /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log file which contains below lines:

```
1527655692: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Thu, 01 Mar 2018 09:34:49 -0500) starting
1527655692: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1527655692: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1527655692: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1527656884: Error in poll: Interrupted system call.
1527656884: mosquitto version 1.4.8 terminating
```

Then I used below command in terminal:

> mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

Again my log output is:

```
1527655692: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Thu, 01 Mar 2018 09:34:49 -0500) starting
1527655692: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1527655692: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
1527655692: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1527656884: Error in poll: Interrupted system call.
1527656884: mosquitto version 1.4.8 terminating
1527656885: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date Thu, 01 Mar 2018 09:34:49 -0500) starting
1527656885: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1527656885: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1527656885: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1527656885: Connecting bridge mqtt (ec2-13-211-229-85.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1883)
1527657360: Socket error on client local.test, disconnecting.
1527657391: Connecting bridge mqtt (ec2-13-211-229-85.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:1883)
1527658711: Saving in-memory database to /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db.
1527658836: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1527658836: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mqttjs_808e4168 (c1, k60).
1527658904: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1527658904: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mqttjs_1ad5b926 (c1, k60).
1527658917: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.1527658917: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mqttjs_89e1b1cc (c1, k60).
1527658922: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
```

After this I tried to publish command from one app to other app(both contains different brokers), but other one is not subscribing to
first app. I don't know where I am going wrong or what extra I have to do..

Comment: Have you restarted mosquitto since deploying the bridge.conf. Also do you see the bridge being started in the logs?

Comment: I restarted mosquitto with this command "sudo service mosquitto restart",but it exited without showing  any logs.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include the log output

Comment: The log output you've posted doesn't show any attempt to set up the bridge. The first set just shows a failed startup, the second is too late after startup to show anything useful

Comment: Now, what I suppose to do?

Comment: Show more (from the start) of the second log